# Python's itertools.compress does not work exactly like a boolean mask. Why?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of strings that I want to filter given a mask of booleans using `itertools.compress`.

I have a large amount of strings I need to check against a list of sentences. Therefore, I want to save resources using itertools. The part that does not work as expected is the Boolean masking via compress.

```py
from itertools import product, starmap, compress

def is_in(string, other_string):
    return string in other_string

to_find = ['hello', 'bye']
some_sentences = ['hello to you', ' hello and bye', 'bye bye']

cartesian = product(to_find, some_sentences)
matched_mask = starmap(is_in, cartesian)
matched = compress(cartesian, matched_mask)
print(list(matched))
```

```py
actual_result = [('hello', 'hello to you'), ('bye', ' hello and bye')]

expected = [('hello', 'hello to you'), 
           ('hello', 'hello and bye'),
           ('bye', ' hello and bye'), 
           ('bye', 'bye bye')]
```

Comment: Product returns an iterator that iterates over each element just once. So you cannot use it twice (once in starmap and once in compress).

Comment: You cannot re-use an iterator, it is single-pass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) returns an iterator, and iterators are generally "single-pass" (there may be exceptions). Once an element is iterated over it won't be iterated over again.

You however use the result of `itertools.product` in two places, once as argument for `starmap` and once as argument for `compress`. So if `starmap` "pops" an element from the `product` then the next time `compress` "pops" an element from the same product it will receive the next element (not the same element).

In most cases I would recommend not to assign such iterators as variables, exactly because of their "single-pass" nature.

So an obvious fix would be to generate the product twice:

```
matched_mask = starmap(is_in, product(to_find, some_sentences))
matched = compress(product(to_find, some_sentences), matched_mask)
print(list(matched))
# [('hello', 'hello to you'), ('hello', ' hello and bye'), ('bye', ' hello and bye'), ('bye', 'bye bye')]
```

In this case I think a loop in a generator function would be more readable than using multiple `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product

def func(to_find, some_sentences):
    for sub, sentence in product(to_find, some_sentences):
        if sub in sentence:
            yield sub, sentence
```

And then use it like this:

```
>>> to_find = ['hello','bye']
>>> some_sentences = ['hello to you', ' hello and bye', 'bye bye']
>>> list(func(to_find, some_sentences))
[('hello', 'hello to you'), 
 ('hello', ' hello and bye'), 
 ('bye', ' hello and bye'), 
 ('bye', 'bye bye')]
```

Or in case you like one-liners:

```
>>> [(sub, sentence) for sub, sentence in product(to_find, some_sentences) if sub in sentence]
[('hello', 'hello to you'),
 ('hello', ' hello and bye'),
 ('bye', ' hello and bye'),
 ('bye', 'bye bye')]
```

Comment: "there may be exceptions" -> out of curiosity, what cases are you thinking of?

Comment: The definition of an iterator requires that it returns `self` in `__iter__` and that it implements `__next__`. However it doesn't state that it may only define these two methods or what `__next__` is allowed to do. One can think of implementations in `__next__` that actually do return the same item multiple times. Or you could even add a method called `go_back_one_element` and call it after each iteration. And of course there is `itertools.tee` (not exactly multiple-pass but it returns multiple iterators that allow to iterate over one iterator multiple times).

Comment: @BradSolomon One well-known exception is the file's iterator - if the underlying file allows reading after EOF, the iterator will happily produce new lines after raising a `StopIteration`. See this [simulation of `tail -f`](https://pastebin.com/HnfiF8SH) for an example.